# How to do curve-fitting with multiple curves and dependent variables

Tags: python, curve-fitting, least-squares, lmfit

I am working on an extended SIR model for covid-predictions. Now I am trying to use curve-fitting through lmfit.

This is the code:

```html
mod = lmfit.Model(fitter)

for kwarg, (init, mini, maxi) in params_init_min_max.items():
    mod.set_param_hint(str(kwarg), value=init, min=mini, max=maxi, vary=True)

params = mod.make_params()
fit_method = "leastsq"
```

I have extended my SIR with an extra "death" case. So now I can curve-fit my model based on the historical "deaths". But I have also found a trustworthy source for possible "infections". The thing is, I can only do the curve-fitting on either the "D" (death) curve or the "I" (infected) curve. Is there some way through which I can use curve-fitting based on two curves which basically are dependent on the same SIR algorithm. For instance, when curve-fitting on "D" I get an R0 of 3.5, with "I" I get an R0 of 4.2. How can I found the R0 value (with other variating parameters) which suits both curves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you have to equations (or functions) that model two different datasets (your "deaths" and "infections") and these share some parameters ("r0"), you can make a model that uses `np.concatenate()` to append the two arrays for the model, and then fit the concatenated datasets.

That concatenated model would have a single set of parameters.  It's OK if some of the parameters really only alter the first or second half of the concatenated data set.

Comment: @FarhangDehzad: Please also accept the answer if it solved your problem; you can do so by clicking the small check next to the answer which then turns green.